# how do i get messages count?

Tags: php, sms, twilio, twilio-php

I am using Twilio PHP library.

I would like to get the total count of messages available in an account.

I use the following code:

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken); 
$messages = $client->account->messages ;
echo count($messages);
```

The count always displays as one (1). Let me know how to get the total count.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest using a [Usage Record](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records) to get this information:

```
// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACed732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659f0"; 
$token = "{{ auth_token }}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

// Loop over the list of records and echo a property for each one
$callRecord = $client->account->usage_records->getCategory('sms');
echo $callRecord->usage;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me explain my requirement in detail. I am creating a log report of messages received / sent. I have pagination system for the report. I need to know the total count of messages for pagination.  To get the total calls the documentation says, we can use  $calls = $client->account->calls; 
echo count($calls); I am looking at similar solution.